# Show username in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i am building a small website with asp.net , c# and is connected to a database and trying to show the username in a label. how can i achieve this.

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Asp.net" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Do you mean the user that is being used to connect to the database?

Answer (score 2):

This gets you the username for the currently authenticated user. I think you should figure out how to get that in a label...

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how your users authenticate, but start with System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.